# Reusing a table - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose we have a big query like:

```
(A joins V) UNION ALL (B joins V) UNION ALL ... (N joins V)
```

Where `V` is the same table for all of the joints and `A`, `B`, ... and `N` are different tables w/ different join conditions.

What would be the efficient way of running this query? Is there a way to avoid loading `V` multiple times into memory?

> A spill to disk during shuffle occurs when the output from a stage
>   does not fit into available RAM in the shuffle infrastructure.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it to see if it works? One of the good things about BigQuery is that you shouldn't have to think about these types of things - most of the time ;-)

Comment: Yes, I've tried it many times; the jobs were completed, but I want to avoid spilling. I provided a part of the profiler's output.